# Is there an easy way to save a section from a rendered web page as an image?

Tags: php, javascript, browser

I want to provide the ability to save some rendered data/charts (with the titles and other information not included in the image) by specifying the coordinates and size in the browser window that contains the data I want to save. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use firefox and X11 virtual desktop on your server and make screenshots.

Like is described [here](http://www.debian-administration.org/article/website_screenshot_server_on_debian_stable)

Comment: I want to do it client side and provide a link to the image if possible.

Comment: It`s not possible with javascript. It`s possible with flash to screenshot itself, but not javasctipt